# Random requests to website

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, webforms

Regularly, I get random page requests to my website. For example some of the requests include:

- '/Pages/49r72acy.aspx'
- '/60islation.aspx'
- /category28_1ls.aspx'

There are many more requests like the above, and obviously it generates a page not found error since I dont have any pages like that. Just curious why this happens. Many thanks.

Comment: Looking at the IIS logs would help determine where these requests are coming from.  You could also do some packet capturing on your server since these happen regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a "bot" looking for some "hole" in your site, or trying to do a denial of service attack (DOS) by flooding your site with spurious requests (that can't come from cache).

Alternatively, if you are employing some penetration testing service or tool, it could also be generating random requests (just like what a "bot" would do).

Comment: Ah - I see. Thanks that makes more sense.